# how to make jquery calendar not to pick current date from system

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have wrong system date set on my system , Jquery Calendar is picking current date as my system's current date .. how to make it to display current date from  Internet 
.can anyone please resolve this issue

Comment: see this [http://forums.asp.net/t/1911632.aspx](http://forums.asp.net/t/1911632.aspx)

Comment: it would be more appropriate to put the right date on your machine instead of looking for work around.

Comment: I can set in my system but i am developing an application and the user might not set the date

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code, Hope it should helpful for you. Thanks

**html:**

```
<input type="text" id="stDate"/>
```

**js:**

```
$(function(){
$("#stDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy', 
                                 changeMonth: true,
                                 changeYear: true,
                                 yearRange: '-70:+10',
                                 constrainInput: false,
                                 duration: '',
                                 gotoCurrent: true}).datepicker('setDate',"0");
});
```

**Sample HTML Page:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <title>
    Date Time Now
     </title>
     <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#stDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy', 
                                 changeMonth: true,
                                 changeYear: true,
                                 yearRange: '-70:+10',
                                 constrainInput: false,
                                 duration: '',
                                 gotoCurrent: true}).datepicker('setDate',"0");
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="stDate"/>            
    </body>
</html>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Jebasuthan/WSTet/)

Comment: @dandamoodi, Please find my latest update. I added Sample HTML Page for you. Hope it should helpful for you. Please check it once again and let me know. Thanks

Comment: @dandamoodi, Have you tried the Sample HTML Page. Please check it once again and let me know. Thanks